Polygon simplification which ensures original polygon is contained within simplified polygon
Question: Polygon Simplification with Containment Constraint
I have a polygon $P$ with $N$ points:
$$
P = \{ p_1, p_2, \dots, p_N \}
$$
I'm looking for a method to simplify this polygon by removing points, similar to the Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm, but with two important constraints:

Epsilon Proximity: Any point $p_i \in P$ must be within a distance $\epsilon$ of the simplified polygon's boundary.

Containment: Any point $p_i \in P$ must lie inside or on the boundary of $P_s$.


Point 1 is the classic Douglas Peucker constraint. Point2 is the extension I'm looking for.
Is there a known variation or algorithm that extends the Ramer-Douglas-Peucker approach to add point 2.
An approximation but broken example I have is below. It is an open contour but you can swap the contained constraint with to the right of

The white curve is the input
The red curve is a douglas Peucker Reduction
The green curve is adding back all points from the original curve till the new curve falls to the right of the original curve.


EDIT:
In geometry and computational geometry, the left-hand rule is often used to define the interior of a shape when traversing a polyline. When you walk along a polyline, the "left side" typically refers to the area that would be contained if the polyline were extended or closed into a polygon. This follows an orientation convention: as you move along the segments of the polyline, the area "to the left" of it becomes the region inside the polygon when the polyline is closed.

Do you want only the vertices of $P$ to be close to the boundary of $P_s$, or do you want all the boundary points of $P$ to be close to the boundary of $P_s$. In the first case, you allow bounding a very thin polygon with all vertices close to the extremities by a triangle, which may be very far from your thin shape.

I've added a picture as to approximately what I'm looking for. The result in the picture is not optimal.

No. They are the same problem. If you are moving around the new polygon anti clockwise then all points that are contained are to the left. It's a little bit different for open polylines but mostly the same. You can't really say contained but to the left is almost the same. At the end points there maybe some ambiguity but some form of extending the open polyline to infinity or closing it can clarify.

A simple (but probably not the more efficient): Build the graph where edges are the valid lines (lines between two points that do not cross the polygon and that stay sufficiently close to the polygon) and oriented following the polygon boundary, then compute the shortest cycle in the graph.

Amazing that people drive by and mark this for closure but don't even bother to comment as to why they think it is not suitable. It had engagement and I even have an interesting algorithm which solves the problem but because it is closed I can't post the solution.

A video of the solved problem
https://imgur.com/Iash397

Possibly it was closed because it's not trivial why "inside" and "to the right" are the same. So it probably suffices to add a vertical line upwards for the first & last point in the picture and then connect them. Then we're back to a polygon, and the last few lines added are always part of the solution, as long as you make them long enough

I'm not sure why it is not trivial. A polyline has direction. When moving along the polyline in one direction left and right is clearly defined. If the polyline is closed and becomes a polygon then left is either inside or outside depending if the polygon is defined clockwise or anticlockwise. This is not complicated.

That is only the case for simple polygons, not e.g. if it's self-intersecting. And if you interpreted right as "right (x-axis-component-wise)", and not "to the right, relative to the edge", then it's easy to get confused.  Another question that popped up is which distance measure you're using. Skipped-point-to-line? Old-Line-to-New-Line?

To the right relative to the edge being traversed. Skipped point to line

Then you should try @caduk's idea. Without containment it's called the Iri-Imai-algorithm (see e.g. https://compgeo.github.io/iri-imai/dist/index.html#resources). Both the algorithm as well as its improvements (see link) are readily adaptable to also take into account containment.

I'll look into it. My algo is. Two indexes A,C pointing to two vertices. Between these two there is 1 remaining active vertex, B. If the max distance of any original vertex in (A,B) is less than eps and satisfies the side rule then mark B as removed. Decrement A or increment C or both so that there is a new B in between. Repeat till no more can be removed. Seems to work and for the number of points I have it is fast enough. It can't guarantee no self intersection at the end but neither could the version of the DP algorithm I was using. I have some special case handling for closed loops.
